# Html table filled using php echo and css?

Tags: php, html, css

How do I make a empty 5x5 table styled with borders so it looks like a grid, then fill it with the numbers 1-25 using a php loop. This is what I have been able to accomplish so far.

**html:**

```
 <table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Php**

```
for($i=1; $i<=25; ++$i) {
        echo $i "<td>";
}
```

**Css**

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        table, td {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
            <?php 
                for($i=1; $i<=25; ++$i) {
                    echo '<td>' . $i . '</td>';
                    if($i % 5 == 0 && $i !== 25) { 
                        echo '</tr><tr>';
                    }
                } 
            ?>
            </tr>
        </table> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: mmm a little mistake.. what's up when **$i=25**?

Comment: @Vixed, you are right, I've added a small check to make sure it doesn't insert an empty `<tr>`

Answer (score 0):

Run two loops(1 for rows & 1 for columns),

```
<?php

    echo "<table border=2>";
    $num=0;
    for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
        echo "<tr>";
        for($j=0;$j<5;$j++){
            echo "<td>";
            echo $num++;
        }
        echo "</tr>";   
    }
    echo "</table>";

?>
```

[PHP fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/87vh-vgx7)

Answer (score 0):

Using Loops I think you can do something like:

```
<html>
  <table>
    <tr>
     <?php 
          for($i=0;$i=25;$i++){
              echo '<td>'.$i;
              if ($i==4 OR $i==8) { echo '</tr><tr>'; }
           }
     ?>
    </tr>
  </table>
</html>
```